# Nested Select in C# Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm new to Linq and have not been able to get this working.

```
public class ItemMaster
{
   public int ItemId{ get; set; }  
   //other fields
   public IList<ItemDetail> Details { get; set; }     
}

public class ItemDetail
{
   public int DetailId{ get; set; }  ;
   public int ItemId{ get; set; }  ;
   //other fields
}
```

My ViewModel has

```
DataTable dtMaster = da.GetItemsMasterDataTable();
DataTable dtDetail = da.GetItemsDetailDataTable();

var list = (from m in dtMaster.AsEnumerable()                                                 
           select new ItemMaster
           {
              ItemId = m.Field<int>("ItemId"),
              //other fields
              Details = (from d in dtDetail.AsEnumerable()
                         where d["ItemId"] == m["ItemId"]
                         select new ItemDetail
                         {
                             DetailId = d.Field<int>("DetailId"),
                             ItemId = d.Field<int>("ItemId")
                             //other fields
                          }).ToList()
            }).ToList();
```

The list does retrieve all the master items but the Details count is always zero. So the nested select is not working. Please help! Thanks.

Comment: What does `d["ItemId"]` return? Perhaps `==` is not the correct comparator.

Comment: I've tried m.Field<int>("ItemId") == d.Field<int>("ItemId") as well. That didnt work either.

Comment: try: where d.Field<int>("ItemId") == m.Field<int>("ItemId")

Comment: My point was that the comparator may not be correct. Maybe you need to use .Equals. If you were getting references types back instead of value types `==` would only match if they were literally the _same_ object, not just two objects that represent the same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Thomas says,

when you access fields using row["columnName"] syntax, value types are boxed. That way the == operator does reference comparsion as opposed to Equals which compares actual values.

Consider following code

```
object foo = 1;
object bar = 1;

// outputs False
Console.WriteLine(foo == bar);
// outputs True
Console.WriteLine(foo.Equals(bar));
// outputs True
Console.WriteLine((int)foo == (int)bar);
```

So change your where condition from

```
where d["ItemId"] == m["ItemId"]
```

to either

```
where Equals(d["ItemId"], m["ItemId"])
```

or

```
where d.Field<int>("ItemId") == m.Field<int>("ItemId")
```